# How to React Native Speech to Text for IOS

Tags: react-native, speech-to-text

I want to speech to text but I not finded working library.

How can I Speech to Text on React Native?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to translate the entire speech at once, I'd use [react-native-voice](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-voice)

If you want to translate the speech in real-time, this is a much longer process. A friend and I are thinking about releasing a module for it soon.

Comment: application fails and closing when using react-native-voice